# Turn off Express.js logs on POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging

I have the code:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var optionsNeedle = {
    compressed: true,
    accept: 'application/json',
    content_type: 'application/json'
};

app.post('/slotc4llb4ckb2b', (req, res) => {
   res.set('Connection', 'close');
   res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
   var request = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))
   switch (request.api)
   {
       case 'do-auth-user-ingame' :

           var datacc = request;
           var data = needle.post('https://example.com:8443/slot_auth', datacc, optionsNeedle, function(err, resp, body) {
               var d = parser.parseFromString(body);
               var x = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
               var text = x.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
               var text = text.replace(/\\/g, "");
               console.log(text);
               var text = JSON.parse(text);
               slot__out(text, function(s){
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(s));
               });
           });

       break;
       case 'do-debit-user-ingame' :

           var datacc = request;
           var data = needle.post('https://example.com:8443/slot_debit', datacc, optionsNeedle, function(err, resp, body) {
               var d = parser.parseFromString(body);
               var x = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
               var text = x.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
               var text = text.replace(/\\/g, "");
               var text = JSON.parse(text);
               slot__out(text, function(s){
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(s));
               });
           });

       break;
       case 'do-credit-user-ingame' :

           var datacc = request;
           var data = needle.post('https://example.com:8443/slot_credit', datacc, optionsNeedle, function(err, resp, body) {
               var d = parser.parseFromString(body);
               var x = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
               var text = x.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
               var text = text.replace(/\\/g, "");
               var text = JSON.parse(text);
               slot__out(text, function(s){
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(s));
               });
           });

       break;
       case 'do-rollback-user-ingame' :
           var data = slot__rollback(request, function(data){
               slot__out(data, function(s){
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(s));
               });
           });
       break;
       case 'do-get-features-user-ingame' :

           var datacc = request;
           var data = needle.post('https://example.com:8443/slot_getfeatures', datacc, optionsNeedle, function(err, resp, body) {
               var d = parser.parseFromString(body);
               var x = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
               var text = x.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
               var text = text.replace(/\\/g, "");
               var text = JSON.parse(text);
               slot__out(text, function(s){
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(s));
               });
           });

       break;
       case 'do-activate-features-user-ingame' :

           var datacc = request;
           var data = needle.post('https://example.com:8443/slot_activefeatures', datacc, optionsNeedle, function(err, resp, body) {
               var d = parser.parseFromString(body);
               var x = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
               var text = x.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
               var text = text.replace(/\\/g, "");
               var text = JSON.parse(text);
               slot__out(text, function(s){
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(s));
               });
           });

       break;
       case 'do-end-features-user-ingame' :
           var datacc = request;
           var data = needle.post('https://example.com:8443/slot_endfeatures', datacc, optionsNeedle, function(err, resp, body) {
               var d = parser.parseFromString(body);
               var x = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML = d.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0].innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
               var text = x.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
               var text = text.replace(/\\/g, "");
               var text = JSON.parse(text);
               slot__out(text, function(s){
                 res.send(JSON.stringify(s));
               });
           });
       break;
       default :
           throw "Unknown api";
   }
});
```

Im using Express.js, but everytime when I recieve POST request to /slotc4llb4ckb2b im getting this throwed in console:

```
{"answer":{"balance":913.08,"bonus_balance":"0","user_id":"3090","operator_id":"20799","currency":"RUB","user_nickname":"mkrdev","auth_token":"9430d855bed21d355c2eeded60ecd070c98fb15f611e4668c6cebde848defd86","game_token":"cc921285abfb29def63ed07696fb6199","error_code":0,"error_description":"ok","timestamp":"1669174133"},"api":"do-auth-user-ingame","success":true}
```

How do I disable it?

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, awkkk999! Please post your code as [*text*, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14469685). Also, can you clarify what you're POSTing and exactly what error you're running in to? That would be helpful to anyone attempting to answer your question.

Comment: I need to recieve POST request on /slotc4llb4ckb2b and Im doing that through express.js, but when I recieve it, it keeps spamming body of this request, how can I turn off logs?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this field, so I can't really suggest any answers. All I'm saying is that you should [edit] your question so that others who actually *do* know this material can help you. That may not sound very useful on its own, but that's how the community in general will perceive posts like these. Editing to improve your question is highly suggested.

Comment: Perhaps remove the line: `console.log(text);`?!

Answer (score 1):

See console object's "api" key, it's "do-auth-user-ingame" and in your code, for this switch case you have put console.log(text) in code block. Remove that line